# Error validando formulario con js

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema y es que estoy intentando validar un formulario de una página que estoy creando, creé un boton para crear un reserva en un restaurante, y que al accionar el botón se validen los datos ingresados. Pero al intentar crear una reserva, no se valida nada.

```
function validarFormulario(){
//remover el mensaje de error(el div)
//$('.alert').remove();

//declaración de variables 
var nombre=$('#nombre').val(),
    email=$('#email').val(),
    cantPersonas=$('#cantPersonas').val(),
    fecha=$('#fecha').val(),
    hora=$('#hora').val();
//validacion del campo nombre completo
if(nombre=="" || nombre==null){
    cambiarColor("nombre");
    mostrarAlerta("Campo obligatorio *Nombre completo*");
    return false;
}
else{
    var expresion= /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/;
    if(!expresion.test(nombre)){
        cambiarColor(nombre);
        mostrarAlerta("No se permiten caracteres especiales o números");
    }
}
//validacion correo(cambio color y caract. especiales)
if(email=="" || email==null){
    cambiarColor("email");
    mostrarAlerta("Campo obligatorio *email");
    return false;
}else{
    var expresion= /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
    if(!expresion.test(email)){
        cambiarColor(email);
        mostrarAlerta("Por favor ingresar un correo válido");
    }
}
//Validacion para campo no vacio sugerencias y consultas
if(sugerenciaConsulta=="" || sugerenciaConsulta==null ||sugerenciaConsulta=="..."){
    cambiarColor("sugerenciaConsulta");
    mostrarAlerta("Campo obligatorio *Sugerencia o consulta");
    return false;
}
//validacion para campo no vacio comunas
if(comunas=="" || comunas==null ||comunas=="..."){
    cambiarColor("comunas");
    mostrarAlerta("Campo obligatorio *comunas");
    return false;
    }
}
```

y aqui el html donde está creado el botón para crear una reserva y validar los datos ingresados.

```
<div class="form-reserva">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='validarFormulario()'> Crear Reserva </button>

        </div>
```

Comment: Agrega tu formulario html y la función `cambiarColor`

Comment: ¿Y que es `sugerenciaConsulta` y `comunas`?  No los veo predefinidos en tu ejemplo. Quizás, al faltarte esas variables, el javascript te peta entero. **Recomendación:** Revisa la consola (pulsa F12 en tu navegador para acceder a ella) cuando ejecutes el script y revisa bien si aparecen errores de javascript.

Comment: Encontré el error, y dice que $ no esta definido.  "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Eso es que no has cargado el jquery aun

Comment: Vale, ahora funciona, no estaba cargado el jquery y no estaba definido Sugerenciaconsulta ni comunas.

Comment: perfecto, me alegro :-) saludos